# Как перенести все свойства класса в таблицу DataGrid?

Tags: c#, datagrid

У меня есть класс со 3 свойствами. И список объектов данного класса.

```
public class Human
{
    public int Age {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    List<double> SomeParam {get;set;}
}
```

Мне надо в таблицу `DataGrid` вывести значения `Age`, `Name` и значения списка `SomeParam` в каждую отдельную колонку. У всех объектов списка длина `SomeParam` одинаковая. Как это можно лаконично прописать?

Вот так - https://pastenow.ru/3117871a3e1b8fda998abe3b08a742e8

Comment: Это что, WPF? Вообще модель данных выглядит как зубчатая коллекция. Очень странная и похожа на ошибку проектирования. Откройте тайну, как так вышло? Быть может модель проще перепроектировать, чем костыли выдумывать?

Comment: Вы хотите примерно так отображать данные в DataGrid? https://pastenow.ru/H51RB

Comment: Можете создать ещё один класс `HimanGrid`, в котором будет не `List<double>`, а просто `double`. Так же, `Age` и `Name` сделать nullable (`int?` и `string?`). Таким образом, заполняя новую коллекцию HumanGrid, не добавляйте ничего в `Age` и `Name`. Либо добавляйте, но не выводите (добавьте атрибут `ColumnVisible(false)` или `BrowsableAttribute(false)`)

Comment: @Frehzy нет, чтобы элементы списка были каждый в отдельном столбце

Comment: @aepot Ну грубо говоря, у меня класс Робот, который торгует на бирже, у него есть свойства ( доходность и т п) и есть список его параметров. Я в таблице уже сравниваю список таких роботов по их доходности, но теперь хочу сравнивать еще и по каждому параметру, который в списке записан. Возможно я криво всё сделал, но по-моему логично. Поправьте меня, если что)

Comment: @Frehzy https://pastenow.ru/3117871a3e1b8fda998abe3b08a742e8 вот так

Comment: Не припомню, чтоб была возможность удобно выводить лист. Вы можете сделать List<double> приватным полем, а от него сделать свойства, которые будут выглядеть примерно следующим образом: `public double FirstParam => SomeParam.First();`. К тому же, если количество элементов, как вы сказали, всегда одно и то же - что мешает сделать так? У этого способа есть минусы. Например, если добавится или изменится количество параметров - придётся изменять количество свойств

Comment: У меня в голове сейчас всплыло, что можно свойства создавать в рантайме, но что-то мне подсказывает, что это крайне плохая затея будет, хоть и будет работать для разного количества параметров

Comment: @Frehzy получается с выводом каждого элемента в отдельное свойство можно так сделать, я тоже не представляю, как нормально список с остальными свойствами вывести. В любом случае спасибо хотя бы за такую идею) Буду иметь в виду)

Answer (score 1):

Я для таких задач написал Generic метод:

```
DataTable ConvertToDataTable<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
     var props = typeof(TSource).GetProperties();

     var dt = new DataTable();
     dt.Columns.AddRange(
     props.Select(p => new DataColumn(p.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(
            p.PropertyType) ?? p.PropertyType)).ToArray()
            );

     source.ToList().ForEach(
              i => dt.Rows.Add(props.Select(p => p.GetValue(i, null)).ToArray())
            );

     return dt;
}
```

И можно просто использовать таким оброзом:

```
DataTable table = ConvertToDataTable(humans);
```

Comment: Метод красивый, но зачем `DataTable`? И этот метод не решает проблему автора, прочитайте вопрос внимательно.